# Error creating bean with name 'consumerController': Injection of resource dependencies failed

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, servlets

I am trying to connect a Rest api with memcached using spring MVC for setting and getting data on memcached which I got from API.
Currently getting this error:

> SEVERE: Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'consumerController': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'memcachedClient': No qualifying
>   bean of type [net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient] found for dependency
>   [net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient]: expected at least 1 bean which
>   qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency
>   annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)};
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient] found for
>   dependency [net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient]: expected at least 1
>   bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
>   Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

ConsumerController:

```
import net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient;


@RestController
public class consumerController {
    @Autowired
      private MemcachedClient memcachedClient;
    @RequestMapping(value="/queues/{queueName}/thread-counts/{threadCount}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void setThreadCount(@PathVariable String queueName, @PathVariable int threadCount) {
        System.out.println("Queue name is "+queueName);
        System.out.println("Thread count is "+threadCount);     
        //memcachedClient.set(queueName, 0, threadCount);
        memcachedClient.add(queueName, 0, threadCount); //Adding value to memcached
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/queues/{queueName}/thread-counts", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getThreadCount(@PathVariable String queueName) {
    System.out.println("Queue value is"+queueName);
    int threadCount = (Integer)memcachedClient.get(queueName);//Getting value from memcached
    System.out.println("Thread count for " + queueName + " is " + threadCount);
    }
}
```

ConsumerConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "msg91.consumers.consumer")
public class consumerConfiguration {

}
```

ConsumerInitializer:

```
public class consumerInitializer  extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { consumerConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

Spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<bean id="memcachedClient"
    class="net.spy.memchached.MemchachedClient">
<property name="servers" value="127.0.0.1:11211"/>
<property name="protocol" value="BINARY"/>
```

Pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.code.simple-spring-memcached</groupId>
   <artifactId>spymemcached-provider</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.google.code.simple-spring-memcached</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-cache</artifactId>
     <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Please suggest me what I am doing wrong in this and how to resolve this error

Comment: Someone please help, I am not able to figure out the problem

Answer (score 0):

In the bean creation you are giving the class as your controller class. So you are creating a bean of your controller instead of MemchachedClient.
Change it to the net.spy.memchached.MemchachedClient.

Comment: Hey, I tried your solution. I have updated the xml in the question too.
Still facing the same error:
 Error creating bean with name 'consumerController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'memcachedClient': No qualifying bean of type [net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient] found for dependency [net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency